# php / database causes performance issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am building an online tool for soccerclubs in php. Part of the system is a match module where you can make a video analysis, give grades to players, and more.

Everything is working fine, only problem being the performance of the initial pageload. The reason behind the problem is the database and the way im getting and presenting the data from the database.

My current database looks like this(I removed all unnecessary fields):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZnpC.png

When I'm done getting my data from my database I have an object like this:
$match->formations[]->positiongroups[]->positions[]->users[]->statgroups[]->stats[]

The way I'm getting the data takes way to much time( about 12 seconds ) and I'm probably doing it completely wrong. You can see the code below. I use laravel 4 as framework so most code isn't plain php but I think when you read the code you will understand what every line of code does. I do want to notice that an non-laravel solution is fine!

```
    /*
    *   Get fullmatch info
    *   Returned value consists of 
    *   $match->formation->positiongroups[]->positions[]->users[]->statgroups[]->stats[]
    */
    public static function fullMatch($id){
        //Get match of given id with formation and team
        $match = Match::where('id', '=', $id)->with('formation', 'team.formation.positions', 'team.category')->first();

        if($match->formation){
            //Set all positiongroups in $match->formation
            $match->formation->positiongroups = Positiongroup::all();

            //Get possible positions
            foreach(Formation::find($match->formation->id)->positions as $position){
                $positions[] = $position->id;
            }

            //Loop through all positiongroups in $match->formation 
            foreach($match->formation->positiongroups as $positiongroup){

                //Set all positions in positiongroups
                $positiongroup->positions = Position::where('positiongroup_id', '=', $positiongroup->id)->whereIn('id', $positions)->get();

                foreach($positiongroup->positions as $position){
                    $position->users = DB::table('formation_position_match_user')
                        ->leftJoin('users', 'user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->where('formation_id', '=', $match->formation->id)
                        ->where('position_id', '=', $position->id)
                        ->where('match_id', '=', $match->id)
                        ->get();
                    foreach($position->users as $user){
                        $user->statgroups = Statgroup::where('video', '=', 1)->with('Stats')->get();
                        $user->stats = DB::table('stat_statdate_user')
                            ->leftJoin('statdates', 'statdate_id', '=', 'statdates.id')
                            ->where('stat_statdate_user.user_id', '=', $user->id)
                            ->groupBy('stat_statdate_user.stat_id')
                            ->orderBy('stat_statdate_user.stat_id')
                            ->get();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $match;
    }
```

If there is more information needed I'm happy to add it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the queries it produces, but I think you have too many nested foreach loops and you are sending too many queries to database. You should minimize number of queries. You can do it manually or use some library. For example [NotORM](http://www.notorm.com/)

*edit: Here is example of what you could easily do and improve the performance:*

You should focus on getting more data at once, than doing it row by row. For example replace some = in WHERE conditions with IN ();

so instead of sending a lot of queries like

```
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE position_group_id = x;
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE position_group_id = y;
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE position_group_id = z;
```

you send only one SELECT to server:

```
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE position_group_id IN (x, y, z);
```

You will have to modify your code, but it won't be that difficult... I don't know how your where method works, and if it supports IN statement, but if it does, do something like this:

```
$position_group_ids  = array();
foreach ($match->formation->positiongroups as $positiongroup) { 
   $position_group_ids[] = $positiongroup->id;
}

$all_positions =  Position::where('positiongroup_id', 'IN', $position_group_ids);
```

Comment: I tought this would be to many nested foreach loops. But the problem is I dont know how to do it with keeping the same results or if that is even possible.

Comment: I updated my answer and added simple example ;) Don't worry, it is possible to improve it and get the same results.

Comment: You should eager load your relationships, this reduces the database queries and solves the n+1 issue. Could you show the queries generated by eloquent?